# Mysql and C# problems and regex

Tags: c#, mysql, regex

i have some problems with commands in mysql. 
Im trying to find all the query's were the name is close to what im typing.

When i maded to search a file, after lot of hours of google and stackoverflow and youtube i found out and maded this comand

```
Regex.IsMatch(lista3, cautClienti, RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

Where ->lista3 is were to search in the file and CautClienti what to search, and this shown me everything-> For example -> if i searched for Mircea -> it would give me Mircea Mihai, Mircea George, Mircea Emil, Mircea, and so on.

Well my problem is, when i try to make it on a mysql command, thing's started to get a bit strange

```
MySqlCommand comanda = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM legitimatii2 WHERE Nume_Abonat ='" + textCautare.ToString() + "' ");
        comanda.Connection = conectare; // sa faca conectarea prin nebunia aia mica

        try
        {
            conectare.Open();


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

        }

        MySqlDataReader citim = comanda.ExecuteReader();
        while (citim.Read())
        {
            ListViewItem Cautam = new ListViewItem(citim["logid"].ToString());
            Cautam.SubItems.Add(citim["Nume_Abonat"].ToString());
            Cautam.SubItems.Add(citim["Data_Start"].ToString());
            Cautam.SubItems.Add(citim["Data_End"].ToString());
            Cautam.SubItems.Add(citim["aid"].ToString());
            Cautam.SubItems.Add(citim["Nume_Abonat"].ToString()); //aici vine promotia!!!!!! DACA E
            Cautam.SubItems.Add(citim["Pret"].ToString());
            listView1.Items.Add(Cautam);
        }
        conectare.Close();
        comanda.Connection.Close();
        comanda.Dispose();
```

What do i have to change at the mysql command to get all type's of variables? I seen something with regex but it somehow different is "REGEXP" .

And my second question is there someway to make in a single mysql command select more tables and values?

Hope you can give me some clues, and some ideas.

Comment: Please do NOT concatenate your parameters into the SQL text. Use parameters. For example: http://www.eiben.weite-welt.com/2011/11/parameterized-queries-in-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

Use like and % in sql command to fetch all variables starting with entered letter

```
MySqlCommand comanda = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM legitimatii2 WHERE Nume_Abonat like '" + textCautare.ToString() + "' 
    %");
```

And to fetch mulitple table write a stored procedure.

Comment: Thank's for the help it was like that, and to get data from more tables and put it in 1 mysql command i done it like this.

Thank you for the hints 
    MySqlCommand comanda = new MySqlCommand("select log.nume, l2.nume_abonat, l2.pret, l2.data_start, l2.data_end, ab.descriere from logare as log, legitimatii2 as l2, abonamente as ab where log.logid=l2.logid and l2.aid=ab.aid and l2.nume_abonat like '%" + textCautare.ToString() + "%'");